# Can I modify doctest to test bash inside sphinx doc?

Tags: python, bash, doctest

My original question was "can I doctest bash"?

I've found a few similar questions, and the answers are pretty much:

1. Use `subprocess`
2. No
3. Use other module (`docshtest` was the best I could find)

---

I want to go on another approach. Is it possible to patch `doctest`? I changed the code myself to run `shell` instead of `python`. Here is my diff:

```
1329,1330c1329
<                 exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
<                              compileflags, 1), test.globs)
---
>                 import subprocess; proc = subprocess.run(example.source, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
1339c1338
<             got = self._fakeout.getvalue()  # the actual output
---
>             got = proc.stdout.decode()  # the actual output
```

which obviously is not ideal, but it gets the job done:

---

Example run:

```sh
(venv) docs$ make doctest
Running Sphinx v4.4.0
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [doctest]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
running tests...

Document: index
---------------
**********************************************************************
File "index.rst", line 3, in default
Failed example:
    echo bla
Expected:
    blu
Got:
    bla
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   2 in default
2 tests in 1 items.
1 passed and 1 failed.
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.

Doctest summary
===============
    2 tests
    1 failure in tests
    0 failures in setup code
    0 failures in cleanup code
build finished with problems.
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'doctest' failed
make: *** [doctest] Error 1
```

This was run on an `index.rst` containing shell examples instead of python examples:

```
.. doctest:: 

    >>> echo bla
    bla
    >>> echo bla
    blu
```

---

So, my question is this - how can I patch doctest to allow users to run bash examples as well as python examples?

Do I need write a wrapper module that mocks things in doctest, or can I fork something (this is an official python library, so I guess not).

**What would be the best way to still use all the goodies `doctest` offers, but tweak its mechanics a bit, in a way that suits me (and I think others)?**

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and ended up writing a [sphinx extension](https://github.com/tillahoffmann/sphinxcontrib-shtest) to run doctests for shell commands. It uses the `doctest` module to compare outputs and supports features like ellipsis to indicate arbitrary output. The syntax closely follows the [`sphinx.ext.doctest`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html) extension (except `>>>` is replaced by `$` to indicate commands).

For example, the following will verify the output of a command.

```
.. shtest::

    $ echo "hello world"
    hello ...
```

Installation instructions and examples can be found [here](https://github.com/tillahoffmann/sphinxcontrib-shtest).

The extension also adds a `.. sh::` directive which can be used to add the output of shell commands to documentation, e.g., to document command line interfaces automatically. The following example would show the `pytest` help.

```
.. sh:: pytest -h
```